# RegEx PHP: strange things with lookaheads

Tags: php, regex

Good day! I have the following pattern:

```
/(?=test)(?=.*la).{8}/
```

to match this:

```
testlaoo
```

And it is working correctly. But I can't understand why do I have to use .* here

Comment: Correct regex would be: `/^(?=test)(?=.*la).{8}$/` and you need `.*` before `la` to be able to match `la` anywhere not just at start.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Don't you have a more detail explanation?

Comment: You can also use a single lookahead: `/^(?=.{8}$)test.*la.*$/`

Answer (score 0):

You know, there are that little stupid questions without which you can't go ahead. It was one of them. 
So, you need .* before la to be able to match la anywhere not just at start.